# Problem possibly with np.apply_along_axis?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am working with the Fashion NMIST data and I am trying to use np.apply_along_axis. I think this is were my issue is. I have tried it with a toy data set of 6-(1,2) points for training and 2-(,2) test points and a 100 point subset of fashion Mnist data with 1 test point and it appears to work. So when I tried it with the more than 2 data points it does not work. I have posted my code and the error below. If anyone could give me any pointers I would greatly appreciate it. I deleted the inside part of the matrices in the error code to make this post shorter, in case anyone is wondering, just left the first and last few lines.

Thanks,
R. Oberoi

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import io

from scipy.spatial import distance 

fashion_mnist = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist

from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = fashion_mnist.load_data()

X1=train_images.flatten().reshape((60000,784))
x1=test_images.flatten().reshape((10000,784))

# Subsetting fashion MNIST to work with

X=X1[0:100,:]
Y=train_labels[0:100]
x=x1[0:3,:]
y=test_labels[0:3]

def CLC(target):
    centroids=[]
    # Find k nearest neighbors by label
    for i in list(labels):
        X_i = X[Y==i]
#    print(X_i)
        Y_i = Y[Y==i]
        nbrs_i = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=1).fit(X_i)
        distances, indices = nbrs_i.kneighbors(target.reshape(1,-1))
    
        # Subsetting data for nearest neighbors
        xss=X_i[indices,:]
        yss=Y_i[indices]
        # Centroid of k nearest neighbors by label
#    print(xss)
#    print(yss)
        centroid = np.mean(xss, axis=1)
        print(centroid)
        centroids.append(centroid)
#centroids
    # find closest local centroid
    centroids=np.squeeze(centroids)
    clf = NearestCentroid()
    clf.fit(centroids, labels)
    return(clf.predict(target))

y_pred=np.apply_along_axis(CLC, axis=1, arr=x)
#acc=sum(y_pred==y)/len(y_pred)
#acc

Error Output:

[[  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0. 122. 101.  73.  59.
   39. 108.  89.  91.  83.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.
    0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   3. 215. 232. 236. 223.


    0.   0.   0.  61.  81.  91.  56.  12.  99.  75.  78.  75.  99.  70.
   61.  70.  77.  77.  61.  58.  89.   7.  55. 188.  97.  78.   0.   0.
    0.   0.   0.   9.  28.  23.   4.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.
    0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   1.  66.  33.  11.   0.   0.]]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-569-bda921e18e4e> in <module>
     26     return(clf.predict(target))
     27 
---> 28 y_pred=np.apply_along_axis(CLC, axis=1, arr=x)
     29 #acc=sum(y_pred==y)/len(y_pred)
     30 #acc

<__array_function__ internals> in apply_along_axis(*args, **kwargs)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/shape_base.py in apply_along_axis(func1d, axis, arr, *args, **kwargs)
    377     except StopIteration:
    378         raise ValueError('Cannot apply_along_axis when any iteration dimensions are 0')
--> 379     res = asanyarray(func1d(inarr_view[ind0], *args, **kwargs))
    380 
    381     # build a buffer for storing evaluations of func1d.

<ipython-input-569-bda921e18e4e> in CLC(target)
     24     clf = NearestCentroid()
     25     clf.fit(centroids, labels)
---> 26     return(clf.predict(target))
     27 
     28 y_pred=np.apply_along_axis(CLC, axis=1, arr=x)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/neighbors/nearest_centroid.py in predict(self, X)
    190         check_is_fitted(self, 'centroids_')
    191 
--> 192         X = check_array(X, accept_sparse='csr')
    193         return self.classes_[pairwise_distances(
    194             X, self.centroids_, metric=self.metric).argmin(axis=1)]

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    519                     "Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if "
    520                     "your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) "
--> 521                     "if it contains a single sample.".format(array))
    522 
    523         # in the future np.flexible dtypes will be handled like object dtypes

ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0

   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

Comment: Why are you using this `apply...`?  Does the function expect a 1d array?  The error implies it doesn't.  Don't try to use a function you don't understand.  It does not improve performance.

Comment: It is supposed to take an array. I am using the function because I have 10000 data points and I would like to vectorize the operation. By choosing the axis it will pull my data by the rows. I have reshaped it to make sure it will be a row vector. Do you have a suggestion on how to get it to work? Or do you know another way I can vectorize the operation?

Comment: `np.apply_along_axis` does not "vectorize".

Comment: For a start just make sure `CLC` works with a row or column of `x`.